# Django Templates: Add something below a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this html django template:

```
{{ header }}

{{ content }}

{{ footer }}
```

This means the context takes these variables: header, content, footer.

Is there something possible like this:

```
Template(...).render(
    dict(header='foo', content='bar', footer='blu', 
        content__post='this should be between content and footer')
```

The needed result:

```
foo
bar
this should be between content and footer
blu
```

I don't want to modify all templates to contain `content__post`, since there are a lot of templates.

How to "inject" snippets post/pre (below/above) the place of other variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the in between content to `content` and there you go. This could be done with a context processor, if you want it completely automated.

```
def add_something(context):
    if somecondition_maybe:
        context['content'] += "some more content to be added"
    return context
```

and then add `your_app.context_processors.add_something` into your template context processors (in `settings.py`).

see more: [own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and [context_processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)